# How do I make my bootstrap navbar stick to the top of the page when scrolling?

Tags: java, spring-boot, navbar

I have a spring boot project and that is a photo of my navbar. I want the nav bar to be stuck to the top of the page when the user scrolls down but I can't figure out how to do it. I am new to front end and I'm struggling to get my head around bootstrap, html and css etc.

```
   <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
     <div class="container">
      <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
      <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-3">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="userProfile1">Home</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-3">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

        <li><a href="/calendar">Calendar</a></li>
        <li><a href="/subjectSearch">Search</a></li>
        <li><a href="/logout">Logout</a></li>

      </ul>

    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container -->
</nav><!-- /.navbar -->
```

This is what my css file looks like:

```
h1 {
color: #78ab46;
 }

 .error-message {
      color: #a94442;
  }

 .error-message:first-letter {
     text-transform: capitalize;
 }
```

Comment: You might want to check out the following link: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_affix.asp

Comment: @BertijnPauwels That worked for me! Thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
```

Adding the above line of code got the nav-bar to be fixed at the top of the page so that it stayed at the top and did not disappear when scrolling.

Answer (score 1):

Hello  Jill you can look up here 
[W3school](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_navbar_sticky.asp)

Also you have here an example you can check the  html code with inspect
[NavBar fixed Top](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/examples/navbar-fixed/)

Also bootstrap v4 here:
[NavBar](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/)

Example (Bootstrap):

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
...      
</nav>
```

and css :

```
.navbar-fixed-top {
    top: 0;
    border-width: 0 0 1px;
}
```

I would use the framework class since its very good to keep the good looking cross browsers and the "same or close" behavior!

Comment: Hi Tiago, I suggest you to add an example since if there is no code, your answer might be flagged and removed.

Comment: Ok Federico i am sorry for it , im new here so im getting use to , how to properly answer!. Thank you for your feedback

Answer (score 0):

The official Bootstrap documentation states, that this piece of code should make the nav bar static to the top:

```
<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Fixed top</a>
</nav>
```

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/navbar/

The relevant class is `fixed-top`, so add this to your main nav container and it should do the trick.

Alternativly you can try to wrap the nav bar in a container and use the general position tools

```
<div class="fixed-top">...</div>
```

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/position/